# The rational form over subfield

Tags: linear-algebra

Let F be a subfield of the complex number.
How to show that the rational form of a matrix over complex is the same over F?

Is it enough to show they have the same min poly and char poly? 
Please give me a hint :)

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the uniqueness of the rational canonical form. The rational canonical form of a matrix over $F$ is also a rational canonical form over $\Bbb C$ and by uniqueness over $\Bbb C$ it is the unique rational canonical form over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: So, you mean that the rational canonical form does not change when extending the field

Comment: How to prove it? What should I do first?